# UITabBar selected background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

i am setting a background image to the selected item of tab bar.

[image]

```
UIImage* tabBarBGImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_image"];
[tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:tabBarBGImage];
```

But the background image comes outside of tabbar.
How can we set the content mode ?

Some answers on stack overflow suggest image resizing, is that the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set clipsToBounds and avoid autoresizing of sub views

```
tabBar.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```